# Disable Item from select box based on value

Tags: javascript, html

What I am trying to do is disable a item from the list when it has been selected from another list.

For Example:
If I select a item in list1, I then want to disable that item in the other lists (list2-list4)

If I then select another item in list1, I then want it to re-enable the previous item from all lists and then disable the new selected item in the other lists.

I want this to happen for all lists. So if I select a item in the other list it should also disable that item in the other lists.

I am trying to do this in JavaScript without using jQuery.

I have 4 select boxes on the HTML page like shown below:

```html
<select id="list1" onClick="disable_item();">
  <option value="000">Item 0</option>
  <option value="111">Item 1</option>
  <option value="112">Item 2</option>
  <option value="113">Item 3</option>
  <option value="114">Item 4</option>
  <option value="115">Item 5</option>
  <option value="116">Item 6</option>
  <option value="117">Item 7</option>
</select>

<select id="list2" onClick="disable_item();">
  <option value="000">Item 0</option>
  <option value="111">Item 1</option>
  <option value="112">Item 2</option>
  <option value="113">Item 3</option>
  <option value="114">Item 4</option>
  <option value="115">Item 5</option>
  <option value="116">Item 6</option>
  <option value="117">Item 7</option>
</select>

<select id="list3" onClick="disable_item();">
  <option value="000">Item 0</option>
  <option value="111">Item 1</option>
  <option value="112">Item 2</option>
  <option value="113">Item 3</option>
  <option value="114">Item 4</option>
  <option value="115">Item 5</option>
  <option value="116">Item 6</option>
  <option value="117">Item 7</option>
</select>

<select id="list4" onClick="disable_item();">
  <option value="000">Item 0</option>
  <option value="111">Item 1</option>
  <option value="112">Item 2</option>
  <option value="113">Item 3</option>
  <option value="114">Item 4</option>
  <option value="115">Item 5</option>
  <option value="116">Item 6</option>
  <option value="117">Item 7</option>
</select>
```

The JavaScript I have tried using is:

```js
function disable_item() {

  var selectobject = document.getElementById("reader1_area")
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    if (document.getElementById("list1").value == document.getElementById("list1").options[i].value) {
      document.getElementById("list2")[i].disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("list3")[i].disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("list4")[i].disabled = true;
    }


    if (document.getElementById("list2").value == document.getElementById("list2").options[i].value) {
      document.getElementById("list1")[i].disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("list3")[i].disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("list4")[i].disabled = true;
    }


    if (document.getElementById("list3").value == document.getElementById("list3").options[i].value) {
      document.getElementById("list1")[i].disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("list2")[i].disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("list4")[i].disabled = true;
    }


    if (document.getElementById("list4").value == document.getElementById("list4").options[i].value) {
      document.getElementById("list1")[i].disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("list2")[i].disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("list3")[i].disabled = true;
    }



  }
}
```

However, I don't think it's correct and I believe there might be a better way in doing this but just can't work it out.

What would be the best way in disabling and re-enabling items based on the item that was selected ?

Answer (score 0):

Look this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y2aqtq9x/2/), jQuery here not used, only pure js. Instead of exlicitly enabling and disabling elements here used events and iteration of child elements:

```
var selects_list = document.querySelectorAll('select');
var selects_array = Array.prototype.slice.call(selects_list);

selects_array.forEach(function(someSelect, idx) {
    someSelect.onchange = function(ev) {
        selects_array.forEach(function(tmpSelect) {

                // Disable options of all select elements
                var tmp_item = tmpSelect.querySelector('option[value="' + ev.target.value + '"]');
                tmp_item.disabled = true;

        });
    };
});
```

Comment: doesn't quite work the way I wanted it to. If you select a item in list1 then it should disable that item in all the other lists. If you then select a item in list2 it should then disable that item in all lists but should also keep the other item disabled that was selected in list1 but I need this to happen with all the lists.

Comment: check my jsfiddle, I've edit some code, so it works now as you described: selecting options disables similar options in all lists, and already disabled options keeps disabled, when you select new one. Hope, I understood you correctly.